# Replacing specific letter in vba

Tags: vba

```
dict = {}
dict['one'] = "This is one"
dict[2]     = "This is two"

tinydict = {'name': 'john','code':6734, 'dept': 'sales'}


print dict['one']       # Prints value for 'one' key
print dict[2]           # Prints value for 2 key
print tinydict          # Prints complete dictionary
print tinydict.keys()   # Prints all the keys
print tinydict.values() # Prints all the values
```

I tried to add the parentheses to the contents of python code and have to replace '#' to ')#' as hash sign implies comments in editor. 
 'print' is also replaced to 'print ('
and appended ')' for python code

The result should have shown like code below

```
print (tinydict.values() )# Prints all the values)
```

I put this code into empty excel sheet and run the vba code below

```
Sub macro1()
Set Rng = Range([a1], [p40])

For Each c In Rng
   If IsEmpty(c.Value) = False Then
        If c Like "*print*" Then
            c.Replace _
            What:="print", Replacement:="print (", _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, lookat:=xlPart

            c.Value = c.Value & ")"   'appending ) at the end'
        End If

        If c Like "*#*" Then
            c.Replace _
            What:="#", Replacement:=")#", _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, lookat:=xlPart
        End If
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

however, it works only to second line of the code

```
print ( dict[2]           )# print (s value for 2 key)
```

rest of the line which contains '#' has not affected.

I've wondered what causes brought up this.

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add Option Explicit to the top of your program.  And then add DIM-s for  Rng  and  c.  But most importantly the problem is

```
If c Like "*#*" Then
```

which looks for a NUMBER somewhere on the line.
This needs to be changed to look for a Pound-Sign by enclosing in square brackets

```
If c Like "*[#]*" Then
```